# is firebase realtime database a mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

say, the Firebase realtime database is a real MongoDb database or it's just a JSON.
I would like to know if it is possible to query this database exactly as if I had a MongoDb database. Queries like:

```
db.users.ensureIndex ({gender: 1, user_name: 1})

db.users.find (gender {"M"}, {user_name: 1})
db.posts.find (POST_TEXT {{$ regex "tutorialspoint" $ options "$ i"}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase database

> Store and sync data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline.
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client

Regarding queries, there is some limitation that you can only query on one node example you cannot do this:

```
Query q=ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(fname).orderByChild("lastname").equalTo(lname);
```

this will work:

```
Query q=ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(fname);
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

Comment: So the answer is "no"?

Comment: yes the queries are different so "no", you can use firestore also from firebase which has much better queries